# Unable to $push and $set the data at a time in mongodb using express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a scenario where I need to replace the data in one array and also push the data in another array in one query itself.
Here I'm using express js framework and mongoose for queries.

Here is the query which I wrote:

```
exports.candidateRating = function(req, res) {
console.log(req.query);
Profiles.update({
    "name": req.query.name
}, {
    $set: {
        "ratings": req.body.ratings,

    }
}, {
    $push: {
        "RoundWiseRatings": req.body.RoundWiseRatings
    }
}, function(error, profiles) {

    if (error) {

    }
    return res.status(200).json(fnStruncturedData(profiless));

});};
```

Here I'm able to set the data but unable to push data.

I don't understand where I'm wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post error msg ?

Comment: @arjunkori
I am not getting any error but the thing is in data base the RoundWise Rating is empty array though i am getting data in req.body.RoundWiseRating

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong syntax, you add $push as another parameter for update function, but you do want to add it as another part of the second parameter.

This is syntax of update

```
Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
```

I think this should work :

```
exports.candidateRating = function(req, res) {
console.log(req.query);
Profiles.update({
    "name": req.query.name
}, {
    $set: {
        "ratings": req.body.ratings,
    },
    $push: {
        "RoundWiseRatings": req.body.RoundWiseRatings
    }    
}, function(error, profiles) {

    if (error) {

    }
    return res.status(200).json(fnStruncturedData(profiless));

});};
```

Also you probably want to update multiple documents, which means you should use multi parameter in options

```
exports.candidateRating = function(req, res) {
console.log(req.query);
Profiles.update({
    "name": req.query.name
}, {
    $set: {
        "ratings": req.body.ratings,
    },
    $push: {
        "RoundWiseRatings": req.body.RoundWiseRatings
    }    
}, {
    multi: true
}, function(error, profiles) {

    if (error) {

    }
    return res.status(200).json(fnStruncturedData(profiless));

});};
```